# LINQ OrderBy Count of Records in a Joined Table

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I'm having trouble translating the following tSQL to LINQ to SQL in C#.  Any help would be much appreciated:

```
SELECT P.Name
FROM Product P
    INNER JOIN OrderItems OI ON P.productID = OI.productID
        INNER JOIN Orders O ON OI.orderID = O.orderId
WHERE P.Active = 1 AND O.Status > 2
ORDER BY count(OI.orderID) DESC
```

It's the ordering by the COUNT of a JOINED table that's throwing me for a loop.

Here's what I have so far (with no orderby):

```
from p in CRM.tProducts
    join oi in CRM.tOrderItems on p.prodID equals oi.prodID
    join o in CRM.tOrders on oi.orderID equals o.orderID
where o.status > 1 && p.active == true
select p;
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: The SQL is questionable -- how do you do a count on an element with no group by?

Comment: You're right.  I didn't actually try the SQL.  What I really want to do is this:

`SELECT
 P.name,
 (SELECT COUNT(OI.OrderItem_ID) FROM Order_Items OI WHERE OI.Product_ID = P.Product_ID) as popularity
FROM Products P
ORDER BY popularity desc`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to execute a group by if you want the count

```
SELECT P.Name
FROM Product P
    INNER JOIN OrderItems OI ON P.productID = OI.productID
        INNER JOIN Orders O ON OI.orderID = O.orderId
WHERE P.Active = 1 AND O.Status > 2
GROUP BY P.Name
ORDER BY count(*) DESC
```

I'll assume you actually want the count for each group in the projection.

```
from p in CRM.tProducts
    join oi in CRM.tOrderItems on p.prodID equals oi.prodID
    join o in CRM.tOrders on oi.orderID equals o.orderID
where o.status > 1 && p.active == true
group p by p.Name into nameGroup
orderby nameGroup.Count()
select new { Name = nameGroup.Key, Count = nameGroup.Count() };
```

Comment: +1 for the nice solution, but I think you meant to put `nameGroup` in place of `myGroup` or vice versa.

Comment: Thanks for the help... I have a followup question.  Basically I want to sort my products by how many times they've been ordered to create a "top sellers" page.  Here's some SQL code that would do exactly that:
      SELECT
     P.name,
     (SELECT COUNT(OI.OrderItem_ID) FROM Order_Items OI WHERE     OI.Product_ID = P.Product_ID) as popularity
    FROM Products P
    ORDER BY popularity desc
    
Could you just literally translate that into LINQ?

Comment: @Steve - it's hard to answer follow-up questions in comment threads - if you post a *new* question, with new sql, I'm sure you'll get some good responses :)

Comment: @Steve - it still looks like you're using COUNT wrong - you need a group by if you want to use count.

Comment: I tried that SQL code and it works correctly.  It's a nested SELECT only pulling 1 item so it can use the count without a group.

Comment: @Steve - ok, sorry, I must have been reading the SQL wrongly - like I said, hard to follow in comments :)

Comment: I just wanted to let you know I managed to figure it out with help from the code you supplied.  Cheers again!  Have a great weekend.

Comment: @Steve - great, you too!  My timezone has about 2 and a half hours to go before the weekend; hopefully you're closer.

Answer (score 0):

See comment to question.

How to do "order by" in linq ->

If you have

```
  var alist = ....  select new { prd = p, ord =  o };
```

you can do

```
  alist.sort( (a, b) => a.ord.CompareTo(b.ord) );
```

to sort it in place.

Comment: The extension method names are OrderBy() and OrderByDescending(), not sort().